# Hide "Comments" section in an individual Confluence page

Tags: comments, confluence

Confluence does not permit disabling Comments per individual [page](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-7742).
However it carries standard *HTML macro*.
What steps are needed to hide the Comments section?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add *HTML macro* to the page
   [image]
2. Insert following code into the *HTML macro*

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        AJS.toInit(function(){
      AJS.$('#comments-section').hide();
        });
    </script>
```

3. *Update* the page and refresh it in the browser (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: Wow, does this work? I thought that the HTML block stripped/sanitized script tags.

Comment: this approach works, and follows the instructions from https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-hide-elements-in-confluence-using-css-or-javascript-313458894.html